# Why does my checkbox get stuck and never return to default?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

I've just made this function to change my page title once the toggle button is clicked but for some reason it gets stuck once clicked. I'm not sure where I am going wrong with this function I have it written in Jquery but it does the same thing even when coded in pure JavaScript. Here it is in Jquery

```
function toggleButton() {
    console.log($('#toggle-employees').prop('checked'))
    if($('#toggle-employees').prop('checked', true)) {
        console.log("true");
        $("#bodyTitle").html("Employees");
    } else {
        console.log("false");
        $("#bodyTitle").html("Roles");
    };
};

<h1 id="bodyTitle" class="navbar-brand"></h1>

<div class="form-check form-switch hidden" id="employee-toggler">
    <input class="form-check-input" onclick="toggleButton()" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="toggle-employees">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="toggle-employees">Employees</label>
</div>
```

Here is a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/oz67jwg8/) to the function in JSPlayground that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `==` or `===` to compare values. `=` is for assignment. Since the `checked` property is a boolean, you can directly use `document.getElementById('toggle-employees').checked` as the condition to check if it is `true`.
- There is no need to set the `checked` property when it changes; it is entirely redundant.

```js
function toggleButton() {
  var paragraph = document.getElementById("bodyTitle")
  console.log(document.getElementById('toggle-employees').checked)
  if (document.getElementById('toggle-employees').checked) {
    console.log("true");
    paragraph.innerHTML = "Employees";
  } else {
    console.log("false");
    paragraph.innerHTML = "Roles";
  }
};
```

```html
<p id="bodyTitle"></p>

<div class="form-check form-switch hidden" id="employee-toggler">
  <input class="form-check-input" onclick="toggleButton()" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="toggle-employees">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="toggle-employees">Employees</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the fiddle for you. You were using "=" to check the isChecked condition. "=" is for assignment use "==" or "===" to compare.